# Match ending bracket only if it exists

Tags: java, regex

Example:

```
a) asdf ghjk (qwer . - tzui
b) asdf ghjk (qwer . - tzui)
c) asdf ghjk (qwer . - tzui) opyx
```

What I want is to match `(qwer . - tzui` in a and `(qwer . - tzui)` in b and c. So if an ending bracket exists, it should only match until that, otherwise until the end.

I'm not really a regex expert so I could only come up with `\(.*\)` for the second and third case which is quite trivial.

Comment: Can brackets be nested? If so, prepare for some difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
\([^)\n\r]*\)?
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2usjj)

The `?` makes the previous expression optional, that means the closing bracket is now optional.

`[^)\n\r]` replaces your `.` to have a non greedy matching and means match every character but `)\n\r`. I added `\n\r` to avoid matching accross rows, if that is now problem you can remove them and leave only `[^)]`

Comment: This works! But why the `\n\r`? I think in my case (just a single line) it's not really necessary.

Comment: In my test on Regexr it was matching from the first row till the "b)" of the second row. If you have only one line you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\)?` at the correct point in your regex to match the closing parenthesis if it exists (or match without it if it doesn't).

The complete regex would look like this:

```
\\(.*\\)?
```

(the double backslashes are needed if the regex is to be entered as a Java string).

Answer (score -1):

To be extremely simplist, you could do:

```
\(.*\)?
```

So that the last parenthesis becomes optional. Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: Well, but then it also matches anything after the last paranthesis which I don't want.